# ASP.NET MVC5 Razor4 @Html.TextBoxFor(type="date")

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html.textboxfor

This makes a really nice control.  But not if I can't use it.  Does it have a feature that lets me set a minimum date as the least date selectable on the control?

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("desired ship on:", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DesiredShipDate, new { @type = "date", @Value=Model.DesiredShipDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I would recommend using something like the [jQuery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) on your textbox which I believe has this functionality.

Comment: Do you know if this picker does or does not have the functionality I'd like to find?  Where is the documentation on these things?

Comment: The "picker" you are seeing is being rendered by the browser you are using based on HTML specs.  You can try adding `@min=` and `@max=` to the attributes you are sending.

Comment: Vakil. max & min don't seem to have any effect in Edge, Chrome, or Firefox for this type.  hmmm..   When I first read your remarks I was like "Well yeah. But that is true of all things web."  but then a light bulb when off.  In Chrome this input type looks awesome! In FF it doesn't even function, In Edge it looks like just about the uglyest thing I think I could ever stand to view.  Back to zgood.  Thanks guys,